# SQL Server WHERE for multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Are there any pros or cons to specifying every matching requirement when joining 3 or more tables (all with inner joins)?

Ex1:

```
SELECT 
    tb1.InvoiceNum, tb2.Name, tb1.DueDate, tb3.TranDate
FROM 
    MFGSYS.PUB.CashDtl tb3, MFGSYS.PUB.Customer tb2, MFGSYS.PUB.InvcHead tb1
WHERE 
    tb2.Company = tb1.Company 
    AND tb2.CustNum = tb1.CustNum 
    AND tb3.Company = tb2.Company 
    AND tb3.Company = tb1.Company 
    AND tb3.InvoiceNum = tb1.InvoiceNum ((tb1.Company='MC') 
    AND (tb1.Posted=1))
ORDER BY 
    tb1.InvoiceNum
```

Does it matter if I leave off `tb3.Company = tb1.Company` since only records from `tb3' where 'tb3.Company = tb2.Company` are selected, and only records from `tb2` where `tb2.Company = tb1.Company` are selected?

Is there any efficiency to be gained (or lost) by removing superfluous joins?

**EDIT:** This is actually SQL commands generated by MSQuery of an ODBC connection (Progress OpenEdge 10.1B).  But I can add or remove 'joins'

Comment: Joins are more efficient than Wheres. Is that what your asking? You might have to just do your own benchmarking.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I probably should have stated that the SQL in question is from MSQuery used to pull data from a Progress OpenEdge DB, via an ODBC driver.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to write this query is with explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT tb1.InvoiceNum, tb2.Name, tb1.DueDate, tb3.TranDate
FROM MFGSYS.PUB.InvcHead tb1 JOIN
     MFGSYS.PUB.Customer tb2
     ON tb2.Company = tb1.Company AND
        tb2.CustNum = tb1.CustNum JOIN
     MFGSYS.PUB.CashDtl tb3
     ON tb3.Company = tb1.Company AND
        tb3.InvoiceNum = tb1.InvoiceNum
WHERE tb1.Company = 'MC' AND tb1.Posted = 1
ORDER BY tb1.InvoiceNum;
```

Where possible, you should stick to only two tables in the `on` conditions.  When not possible, use multiple tables, of course.  Redundant conditions are unnecessary (by definition) and make the query more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to sql-server, I have found that nested selects in many cases are faster than joins (specially if you have a large number of joins.) Nested selects are best used when you fetch a single column value from each of the joined tables.

In your query, most of the work is done against `tb1`, you just fetch some data for presentation from the other tables, so you could try this:

```
SELECT tb1.InvoiceNum,
       (SELECT tb2.Name FROM MFGSYS.PUB.Customer tb2 WHERE tb2.company = tb1.company AND tb2.CustNum = tb1.CustNum) AS Name,
       tb1.DueDate,
       (SELECT tb3.TranDate FROM MFGSYS.PUB.CashDtl tb3 WHERE tb3.Company = tb1.Company AND tb3.InvoiceNum = tb1.InvoiceNum) AS TranDate
FROM MFGSYS.PUB.InvcHead tb1
WHERE tb1.Company = 'MC' AND tb1.Posted = 1
ORDER BY tb1.InvoiceNum
```

Might be faster than joins, might not, you'll have to try.

Comment: I would like to see a real example of where this is true.

Comment: I can describe it, it was a query with a total of 19 joins, many of which against the same table (which contained code, (code type, code, value)-tuples.) I changed the joins with nested selects and got it down to 5 joins, and the query time dropped from a few hours to a few minutes.

Comment: Checked the old query, and you really don't want to see it :p But I see now that the joins were all left joins, which are of course slower than inner joins. With nested selects you get the advantage of a left join, as it won't leave out a row if the inner select returns nothing, while getting the speed of an inner join.

Comment: I am going to have to politely disagree with your last comment. Unless you have something that proves the performance benefit that contradicts everything I have seen over the years. A subquery in the select portion of a query is almost always a recipe for poor performance. I would love to see something that proves otherwise.

Comment: Disagree all you want, the performance went up greatly after replacing a bunch of left outer joins with nested selects. This was on sql-server, I'm guessing that they have optimalizations for nested selects.

Comment: I am interested in seeing some performance benchmarks that support this claim. I have seen (and done) many such benchmarks over the years that contradicts this with subselects. I am open to this as a concept but am curious if this is accurate and what caused the performance to increase drastically with a nonstandard approach.

Answer (score -4):

First of all, what you have is not an explicit join. Its a crude version of a cross join which does not need links between every table. Secondly, ofcourse removing redundant `WHERE` clauses will improve the code and improve the performance. But as Gordon Linoff suggested, try going for explicit `JOIN` syntax always as they are concise and generally faster.

Comment: The source of the SQL code is MSQuery used to create a query of a Progress OpenEdge DB, via ODBC.

Comment: @downvoters: For the sake of my benefit, please atleast tell me why I was downvoted.

Comment: @PPH - so you have not much control on how the final query looks.

Comment: @ Sourav_Agasti - No.  I can add or remove the 'superfluous' joins in MSQuery.  When you add a table in MSQuery, it automatically makes every possible inner join to every table already in the query (often wrongly so).  And I didn't vote you down.

Comment: That's fine. I don't care much about being voted down as long as I understand why. And sorry, I never worked on MSQuery so really not in a position to contribute, but thanks for the info :)

Comment: Probably why I was down voted was I used the term cross join. I know that in this case the execution plan would be similar to an inner join but generally speaking(AFAIK), a syntax without explicitly involving the keyword JOIN is as good as a cross join.

Comment: Yes when you have two or more tables separated by commas it is an implicit cross join. Prior to ANSI-92 this was the only way to join tables. You then would filter it with the where predicates. My guess for the downvotes is that your answer is more like a comment than a full fledged answer.

Comment: Well, the question started off as "does it matter.." and that's what I precisely answered. I still don't understand if my answer was down voted on the sole ground of it being subjective :)